# How to automatically detect sentence fragments in a text file

Tags: nlp, detection, sentence

I am working on a project and need a tool or an API in order to detect sentence fragments in large text. There are many solutions such as OpenNLP for detecting sentences in given file. However, I wasn't able to find any explicit solution to the problem of finding words, phrases or event character combinations which are not belong to any grammatically correct sentences.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Lorderon

Answer (score 1):

you could use n-grams as a work around:

Suppose you have a large collection of text with real sentences for reference. You could extract all sequences of 1,2,3,4,5, or more words and then in your text double check if the fragments from your text exist as n-grams.

you can download n-grams directly from google: http://googleresearch.blogspot.de/2006/08/all-our-n-gram-are-belong-to-you.html but you might need a lot of traffic.

You could also count the n-grams yourself in this case you can take the parsed data sets of the wikipedia from my website: 
http://glm.rene-pickhardt.de/data/ and the source code from https://github.com/renepickhardt/generalized-language-modeling-toolkit in order to create the ngrams yourself (or any other ngram toolkit like srilm, kylm, opengrm,...)

Comment: Hi Rene. Thanks for your reply. I not quite sure if n-grams would help me. How would you be sure that say 5-grams or even 3-grams sometimes are not a single sentence? I'm just trying to figure that out because I'm not a computational linguistics guy.
Also, how would I double check if the false positives are not large when I have a big text data.